# Find values that satisfy 2 criteria (range and an accuracy bw 2 choices) within response data

Tags: matlab, find, range, conditional-statements, matching

Suppose I have the data from a trial I ran that contains one column of the buttons pressed (between buttons 49 and 50) and another column containing the response times.

Now, I wish to compute the accuracy of these results.

This has to depend on:

1. Selecting the correct response key (49 or 50) AND
2. Having this correct response key match within a +5sec period after the time of the stimuli presentation (recorded in another table)

I have figured out a way to get whether the response times fall within the 5 sec range of the stimuli presentation... however I'm unsure as to how I can bind the two so that the correct key press is associated with the specific 5 sec response time...

I hope this makes sense and thank you so much in advance!!!!

Comment: Do you have some code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The logical operator is and (&) as in most if not all programming languages. 
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/and.html 
Matlab even gives you the possibility to logically control to inputs of the same size and returns an output of the given size. You could use sth. like this:

```
ArrayOfButton = (1 for true 0 for false);
ArrayOfTime = (1 for under 5 sec 0 for over 5 sec);
result = ArrayOfButton & ArrayOfTime;
```

The result will then contain a 1 if both the right button was pressed AND the reaction time was under 5 secs. Otherwise it will contain a 0. This also works for matrix. If those have the same dimension (as shown in the hyperlink).